# Issue finding Windows File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file

I'm trying to read some text files for different trucks storing latitude and longitude data, but having trouble finding the files on the Windows PC where they're saved.  I've tried multiple gps_file variables (see below) but every time in production, I get a cannot find file error (Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - C:\Rtmx\Reports\2014\January\08\53.txt)). When I "copy file as path", I get this string - "C:\Rtmx\Reports\2014\January\08#{truck_number}.txt", which seems to match in my heroku logs but still throwing the error.  When I try on my mac in dev through a different file structure, it works fine.  I've been stuck on this issue for hours. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

When I open the file in Chrome, I get the following path for one of the trucks: file:///C:/Rtmx/Reports/2014/January/08/75.txt

```
def update_locations
    require 'csv'
    @locations = Location.where(id: [3,4])

    @locations.each do |location|
       gps_file = "C:\\Rtmx\\Reports\\#{DateTime.now.strftime('%Y').to_s}\\#{DateTime.now.strftime('%B').to_s}\\#{DateTime.now.strftime('%d').to_s}\\#{location.locationable.name.to_s}.txt"
        data = File.read(gps_file).gsub(",","")
        csv = CSV.parse(data, :headers => true)
        @location_log = Array.new
        csv.each do |row|
          row = row
          @location_log << row
        end
        @latest_location_data = @location_log.last
        csv_array = "#{@latest_location_data},String".parse_csv
        array = csv_array.first.split("\t")
        raw_latitude = array[11].split(' ')
        latitude = raw_latitude[0].gsub("N","").to_f + raw_latitude[1].to_f/60 + raw_latitude[2].to_f/3600
        raw_longitude = array.last.split(' ')
        longitude = (raw_longitude[0].gsub("W","").to_f + raw_longitude[1].to_f/60 + raw_longitude[2].to_f/3600)*-1
        location.update(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
      end
    redirect_to locations_url
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to trying to read a file on a user's computer via a controller.  I instead pushed the files to Amazon S3 in real-time as modified and read from there in the controller.

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

@locations = Location.all
    def test_url(gps_file, location)
      begin
        data = gps_file.read.gsub(",","")
        csv = CSV.parse(data, :headers => true)
        @location_log = Array.new
        csv.each do |row|
          @location_log << row
        end
        @latest_location_data = @location_log.last
        csv_array = "#{@latest_location_data},String".parse_csv
        array = csv_array.first.split("\t")
        lat = array[11]
        if lat[0].present?
          raw_latitude = lat.split(' ')
          latitude = raw_latitude[0].gsub("N","").to_f + raw_latitude[1].to_f/60 + raw_latitude[2].to_f/3600
          raw_longitude = array.last.split(' ')
          longitude = (raw_longitude[0].gsub("W","").to_f + raw_longitude[1].to_f/60 + raw_longitude[2].to_f/3600)*-1
          speed = array[7]
          location.update(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, speed: speed)
        end
      rescue
      end
    end
    @locations.each do |location|
      s3=AWS::S3.new(access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'], region: 'us-east-1')
      gps_file = s3.buckets['wheresmyconcrete'].objects["real/#{DateTime.now.strftime('%B').to_s}/#{DateTime.now.strftime('%d').to_s}/#{location.locationable.name.to_s}.txt"]
      test_url(gps_file, location)
    end
```